# Richfaces Datatable - Sort specific column on load

Tags: jsf, richfaces

Is it possible to sort a datatable by a specific column when it first loads? Or does it need to be done using the DAO? When I put on ORDER BY in my SQL in my DAO, no data at all is returned in the datatable

Comment: your question is unclear and no code is provided

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it used `sortOrder="DESCENDING"` or `sortOrder="ASCENDING"` on the column you wish to have sorted when datatable first loads

Comment: Doesnt work for me during initial load. But it sorts once I manually click on the column. Could you please let me know if I could be missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Just need to add this to options:

```
"aaSorting": [[ 5, "desc" ]]
```